# Self-made Yahoo query for Finance data - error with pandas read_csv

Tags: pandas, python-requests

Since the yahoo api does not work I tried a tiny python script to mimic a csv download.
Unfortunately I get back: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized 
But when I just copy paste the URL into the browser it downloads just fine.

This is the code I use:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import requests

stock='TSLA'

url=("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{}?period1={}"
     "&period2={}&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=VLglg7iuqLW")

URL=url.format(stock, 
               int(dt.datetime(2013,1,10,0,0).timestamp()),
              int(dt.datetime(2017,11,25,0,0).timestamp()))

tsl=requests.get(URL).content
tsla=pd.read_csv(URL) #gives an error
tsla.head()
```

The resulting URL is: 
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TSLA?period1=1357772400&period2=1511564400&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=VLglg7iuqLW

and the result is:
tsl=
b'{\n    "finance": {\n        "error": {\n            "code": "Unauthorized",\n            "description": "Invalid cookie"\n        }\n    }\n}\n'

Any idea what I missed?

What's different when using these line versus the copy-paste-browser method?

Comment: Your browser has stored cookies, while `requests` or `pandas` don't. When i open your url in my browser it gives me the same error. Try with `requests.session()`

Comment: OK. Thx. I thought the cookies are in browser anyway...

Comment: I don't know about `pandas`, but [`requests.session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) uses cookies too.

Comment: You may be able to run this same process with finance.google.com, which doesn't need cookie + crumb combinations

Comment: Sorry. It seems finance.google.com doesn't work neither. Before my little code I tried this: spy_etf = web.DataReader('SPY','google') and the result was an error.